# Can I use continuous probability distributions when creating an SDDP.jl model?

Tags: dynamic-programming, julia, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming

I am using [SDDP.jl](https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl) for my research project and want to use continuous distribution, can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the SDDP.jl documentation, the answer is no. But see below for a workaround.

Per [States, controls, and random variables 3.](https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/tutorial/first_steps/#States,-controls,-and-random-variables)

> Random variables are finite, discrete, exogenous random variables that
> the agent observes at the start of a node, before the control
> variables are decided.

Per [Assumptions](https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/tutorial/first_steps/#Assumptions)

> Assumption 2: finite random variables
>
> The sample space $\Omega$ is finite and discrete for each node $i\in N$

Per [Random variables](https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/tutorial/first_steps/#Random-variables)

> To add an uncertain variable to the model, we create a new JuMP
> variable inflow, and then call the function SDDP.parameterize. The
> SDDP.parameterize function takes three arguments: the subproblem, a
> vector of realizations, and a corresponding vector of probabilities.

The remainder of this post is my commentary.

So if you have a continuous distribution (random variable), you would have to discretize it, and input the vector of discrete values and corresponding vector of probabilities.

Comment: Mark's answer is correct. This part of the documentation explains how to sample from a continuous distribution: https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/guides/add_multidimensional_noise/#Sampling